# AdMob : Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView

Tags: android, exception, layout, admob, ads

I've got a simple linearlayout with an advert on it. When I launch the application, I've got this error :

```
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at com.devspark.sidenavigation.SideNavigationView$SideNavigationAdapter.getView(SideNavigationView.java:248)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:638)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4930)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3087)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.widget.AbsListView.startScrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3032)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3357)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4342)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4382)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:530)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 19:00:02.337: E/AndroidRuntime(11395):    at andr
```

The latest AdMob library is referenced both times. The jar is located in the `libs` folder and I added it to the Java Build Path.

Here is the layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.natinusala.pebkac" 
    xmlns:ads="schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/side_navigation_item_padding_topbottom"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/side_navigation_item_padding_leftright"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/side_navigation_item_padding_topbottom"
     >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/advert"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundColor="#000000"
        app:keywords="Android game"
        app:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        ads:addSize="BANNER" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Binary XML file line #34, i think you should check Line number **35**,
i think problem is here 
android:visibility="gone" which means View will no longer available, use android:visibility="invisible"

Comment: But why are you setting visibility as gone ? why are you using it admob if dont want to show it?

Comment: I removed the visibility property and now there is still the same error but there is not any `Caused by...` text... Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I think

instead of android:visibility="gone"

use android:visibility="invisible"

Comment: Working only after completely removing the 'android:visibility=""'

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Properties of your eclipse project, Java Build Path, Order and Export, check the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar entry and move it to the top of the list.

That worked for me having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to add admob jar file to the project library (lib folder). Just simply copy and paste it into lib folder of project. This works sometimes.

If above solution not worked then right click on project, select option Build Path-->Configure Build Path then  select add jar option, select your project, select lib folder of your project, select the .jar file that you want and click OK and restart your Eclipse once. (This procedure is for Eclipse IDE).

Answer (score 0):

i notice your code :

```
xmlns:ads="schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

In Google Developer Page,the sample code is :

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

and remember to Select the Order and Export(Properties>Java Build Path) tab; then, check the Google Mobile Ads JAR to include it when compiling your project.

See it helps or not